# why does type inference break with SelectedItemCollection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

The ASPXCheckBoxList has a collection called 'SelectedItems' of type 'SelectedItemCollection' (it implements ICollection, IEnumerable)

for some reason, there's a difference between this:

```
foreach (ListEditItem si in cblCommonJointOwnership.SelectedItems)
{
    //do stuff and have si.Value and si.Text and si.Foo
}
```

and this:

```
foreach (var si in cblCommonJointOwnership.SelectedItems)
{
   //seems that si is just a plain object here...
}
```

I realize this isn't DevExpress specific.. so I suppose a general question: why does the 'var' version become inferred as an object instead of a ListEditItem?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SelectedItemCollection` implements `IEnumerable` but not `IEnumerable<T>`. Because of that, the compiler doesn't know anything about the type stored in the collection and has to assume the most generic type (which is `Object`).

Your first statement specifies the type. This actually will result in a cast of each item in the collection back to your specified type and would fail if any of the elements in the collection couldn't be properly cast.

Answer (score 3):

Because `SelectedItems` is a specialized collection. It's not generic either. This makes it impossible for type inference to operate.

Put another way, the objects in that list could be anything; even of different types. Therefore, the collection doesn't provide any typed result.